# Text cutting off in Internet Explorer when using text-shadow

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I recently built this website: http://billy.fm/

If you open this page in *Internet Explorer 11*, you'll see that the large title that reads *Samuel-613*, is cut off on the right.

Disabling the `text-shadow` property on this heading in IE developer tools appears to fix the issue.

Also, changing the blur radius to a larger number also works - but leaves me with a result I'm not after.

```
/* Does not work */
.project__title {
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}

/* Works */
.project__title {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
}
```

Weird bug - any ideas?

I am using *Internet Explorer 11* on *Windows 7*. This could be happening in other versions too.

Comment: on win10 ie11 its not cutoff

Comment: In Win7, IE10. Yes it is cut-off.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, IE11. I updated my question to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: the negative letter spacing is causing this issue. probably an ie bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the negative `letter-spacing` is causing this issue. You might want to add some `padding-right` to the span, without having to adjust the `letter-spacing` nor `text-shadow` at all.

Comment: @ManojKumar for instance

Answer (score 1):

**Bug:**

The blur-radius value of 2px in [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) is causing the Win7 + IE11 bug. It is the value of setting shadow to a wider value. Set it to 0 or remove it to solve the cut-off.

**Alternate solution**

The cut-off can be solved by modifying the `letter-spacing` property.

In order to preserve the spacing and remove the cut-off you can go as far as `-0.08em` with current setup.

```
.project__title span {
    letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may be true, what is the connection to text-shadow? Disabling just the text shadow also fixes the issue.

Comment: You are right here. blur-radius might be/is the culprit. IE11 + Win7 bug maybe.

Comment: how can the blur radius be the problem? The blur radius on the text shadow is intended/ wanted :)

Comment: Nope, I just rephrased that to bug :) `Problem` doesn't seem fitting here ;)

Comment: Whilst you provide a solution, removing the shadow or the letter spacing is not an option for this design. So, adding a padding right seems to be the best course for me. You mentioned this in a comment below, but I'll accept this as the answer. Update your solution to include the padding if you will. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I think you should accept Alex's answer. I just commented there for specific solution from his idea. Regards! :)

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo Why do you accept this answer when I provide the solution? :) Not that I hunt for rep, just wondering. Manoj thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Alex - Apologies, I didn't see that you had said the same thing at the time I had read the comment. Credits to you now! Thank you both.